# JPA eager fetching and pagination best practices

Tags: jpa, pagination, jpql, eager

After some research I've found a lot of materials on how to write simple and efficient code (using JPQL) that:

1. Allows eager fetching of related entities (e.g. using JOIN FETCH).
2. Allows pagination on a single entity.

But when it comes to combining both of them - it becomes unclear how to do that in an efficient and clean manner.

- Either it is eager fetching that works, but pagination is being applied in memory (a.k.a. *HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!*)
- Either it is pagination that works, but eager fetching does not (even when a `resultSet` actually contained related entities), resulting in an additional queries to a database to fetch related entities for each row in a batch.

---

The closest thing, that actually works is 
https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/

But it left me wondering if there is a more intuitive and clean solution to the problem?

**Question**: Is there any other best practice on how to use pagination with eager fetching of related entities?

**Note**: Solution should also provide a way to apply filters to data being retrieved from a database. (e.g. *JPQL WHERE clause*)

Comment: A simple solution is to just fetch a page of IDs (applying max results), and then query for all the entities, including joined entities using a join fetch, that have one of the IDs retrieved in the first query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest approach for this problem is using two queries:

1. The first query to apply the **where** condition and **pagination**. The query returns only the ids
2. The second query you use the ids returned on the first query and make the `FETCH`s on the entities related.

As example, the first query:

```
String jpql = "SELECT user.id FROM User user WHERE user.name = 'John'"

Query q = em.createQuery(jpql); 
q.setFirstResult(0);
q.setMaxResults(10);

List<Long> ids = q.getResultList();
```

The second query:

```
String jqpl = "SELECT user FROM User user JOIN FETCH user.address WHERE user.id IN (:ids)"
Query q = em.createQuery(jpql); 
q.setParameter("ids", ids);

List<User> users = q.getResultList();
```

Pay attention if you need to **order by** some column. The `order by` clause needs to be present on these two queries, because the database don't respect the `id` order that you pass by parameter when the database return the rows.